# How does heroku come up with app names?

Tags: heroku, names

Curious how heroku creates app names. The app names are usually english words such as bloom-peaks or formal-trail. This was also the case with the IT department at a big company. Is there a unix library that does the name generation?

Comment: I don't think it was a question about why the names are that way or not liking them, so much as a curiosity about how they are generated. Or at least I answered it from that view.

Comment: We have no way to know how Heroku do it. However, given that assembling words from preset dictionaries using a random number generator and a uniqueness check is very simple, I doubt they required a library for it. They would have needed a dictionary, however.

Answer (score 10):

We wrote our own code to generate the names, it is pretty simple. Basically there is a list of adjectives, and one of nouns. We pick one of each at random and append a random number, then we check to ensure we didn't randomly pick an existing name (if we did, we just try again) and then give that back. Hope that helps!